# Update matplotlib animation manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I can't seem to find any solution to the problem I have, so I'll post a question, even though it seems like there should be a simple solution somewhere.

I want to use a live plot in tkinter and found matplotlib animation to be the best solution. However, I want the plot to update on specific lines in the code. Is there a way to do this? (Not based on an interval)

```py
f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)

def animate(i):
    a.plot(lidarX, lidarY, '.g', markersize = 0.5)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=1000)


# Code to add the figure to a FigureCanvasTkAgg and pack it to the gui
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `a` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "to update on specific lines in the code", some more details could be useful.

In any case, `FuncAnimation` is designed to update a plot at a specific interval, so if that's not what you want to do, the best strategy is to *not* use FuncAnimation.

You can easily update your plot "manually" by calling

```
def animate(i):
    a.plot(lidarX, lidarY, '.g', markersize = 0.5)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```